# many to many to many with entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

OK. Problem as follows

I have a db-table "companies"
a "company" belongs to a "market"
Each company can have events in one or more "months"
*ex: Company belongs to market B and having events in March, May and August*

This leaves me with 3 tables

**Months**
*many-many with*
**Companies**
*many-many with*
**Markets**

Table layout:
**Months**
 MonthID
 Name

**Companies**
CompanyID
CompanyName
[some more]

**Markets**
marketID
Name

EF then creates relational tables.

i have created this with EF 4.1 Model-first and have managed to make a list for all months/companies 
db.Companies.Where(c=> c.Markets.Any(m=> m.Id==12)).ToList() returns all companies in market with id=12
db.Months.ToList() obviously returns months and ALL companies having a event that month

but i dont manage to get a month-listing for  only the companies in market X

**Edit: Example To Clarify:**
The companies A and B and C have events in may and/or august
A and B belongs to market X, C Belongs to market Y

So a listing for market X should be:
january
february
march
april
may
Company A
Company B
june
july
august
Company A

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Months for only the companies in market X can be found like so:

```
db.Months
    .Where(m => m.Companies
        .Any(c => c.Markets
            .Any(x => x.Id == X)))
```

But the word "only" is a bit elusive here. The query is about companies in market X, but not necessarily "only" in market X. I think that's what you mean. It would be slightly different to get months for companies that are all in market X (i.e. one of their markets is X):

```
db.Months
    .Where(m => m.Companies
        .All(c => c.Markets // All
            .Any(x => x.Id == X)))
```

Comment: That one gave actually the same result as db.Months.ToList()
A a example. 2 Companies that belongs to Market X have events in may and august. So obviously I need to exclude all companies that NOT belongs to market X somehow

Comment: hmm, gives same result.
See new edit of orginal post.

Comment: OK, after your addition, another try.

Comment: Well, thats odd.. Gives me an empty list...
The first edit( Any(c => c.Markets.All(x => x.Id == X))) ) Actually gave a "decent" result. 
It returns only the correct months, and then ALL companies having events in these months, even if the company belongs to another market... Gahh back to the drawingboard